# Using Grails internal DB

Tags: database, grails

I am creating an application using Grails Framework for which I plan to use the database which is provided by Grails.
Just wanted to be sure of the advantages/disadvantages before proceeding.
Does using the internal database invite issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Grails has an in-memory database, which means, that whenever you shut down your application, all your data is lost... probably not what you want.

You could change this to a file-database, and this file-database would by default end up in your Grails application root. If you deploy this to an app server and undeploy again, your data is lost... again, probably not what you want.

I would recomend installing a MySql database. It's easy, and you have your data separate from your application.

Comment: thanks sbglasius....u hv given the exact reasoning of what I was looking for...Thanks! deserves a vote up..

Answer (score 2):

The internal database is an in-memory database, so all your data disappears when the server is restarted. It seems very unlikely that you would want this behaviour for a real application, so I recommend MySQL, Postgres (or similar) instead.